# sequence point and side effects

Tags: c, post-increment, sequence-points

According to sequence point definition,  sequence points are "*specified points in the execution sequence called sequence points, all side effects of previous evaluations are guaranteed to be complete*"

So in the below program, all side effects of `++` operator must have been performed before going to second part of `&&` operator, i.e, `i` should be incremented to 1 as `&&` is a sequence point.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0,a;
    a=i++&&1;
    printf("%d",a);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

> 1 (`1&&1=1`)

actual output :

> 0

Why doesn't `i` increment before 2nd part?

Using the ternary operator also gives same output:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0,a;
    a=(i++)?1:0;

    printf("%d",a);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The ternary operator is also a sequence point. So shouldn't this give output 1 instead of 0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
i++
```

Evaluates to previous value of `i`.

As a side effect value of `i` is incremented by `1`.

So yes the sequence point is there but the expression `i++` evaluates to `0` (though value of `i` is `1` at the same time)

For the expected results [use `++i` instead of `i++`](http://ideone.com/DbkPVV).

From **6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators** in C11 specs:

> The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand. As
>   a side effect, the value of the operand object is incremented (that
>   is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to it). See the
>   discussions of additive operators and compound assignment for
>   information on constraints, types, and conversions and the effects of
>   operations on pointers. The value computation of the result is
>   sequenced before the side effect of updating the stored value of the
>   operand. With respect to an indeterminately-sequenced function call,
>   the operation of postfix ++ is a single evaluation. Postfix ++ on an
>   object with atomic type is a read-modify-write operation with
>   memory_order_seq_cst memory order semantics.<sup>98</sup>)
>
> <sup>98) Where a pointer to an atomic object can be formed and E has
>   integer type, E++ is equivalent to the following code sequence where T
>   is the type of E:</sup>
>
> ```
> T *addr = &E;
> T old = *addr;
> T new;
> do {
>   new = old + 1;
> } while (!atomic_compare_exchange_strong(addr, &old, new));
> ```
>
> <sup>with old being the result of the operation. Special care must be taken
>   if E has floating type; see 6.5.16.2.)</sup>